# Lazarus Terminal Output Not Shown (Version 2.0.10)

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

So I recently installed Lazarus and created a simple Hello World Program. When I ran it, no terminal showed up with the output.

Here is my code:

```pascal
program project1;
begin
  writeln ('Hello, world.');
  readln;
end.
```

I saw a question very similar to this. The answer said to click `View > Debug Windows > Terminal Output`. When I click `View > Debug Windows`, there is not option: `Terminal Output`. I'm on macOS Catalina. Is there some change to the way that you are supposed to this.

Here are the options for `Debug Windows`:

[image]

I also do see a message saying the compilation ran successfully (in green).